# EsLint doesn't understand AngularJs Functions have lots of params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint

Our (legacy) code base has lots of AngularJs functions that take a ton of params, which eslint is complaining about (and well it should, it's much easier to read a function with fewer params. We've got a *very* lenient max of 8.

I've seen this question, about [jshint max-params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038080/this-function-has-too-many-statements-41), but I'm hoping there's either a solution in Angular, or one in eslint. None of the answers there are relevant and useful.

Futher more, we're using `export` so our code actually looks like:

```
FunctionWithABillionParamsService.$inject = [/*billion params*/]
export default function FunctionWithABillionParamsService(/*billion params*/){..}
```

How can I either tell eslint not to worry about AngularJs stuff (functions with an `$inject` property?), or alternative ways to create a function without/fewer the params?

Comment: You can just use single params param which is an object.

Comment: @dfsq [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)?