# What does it mean when it says " This function has too many statements (79) "? This is JavaScript by the way

Tags: javascript

What does it mean when it says that the function has too many statements? Is there a maximum code length I can have in functions? If you have any recommendations on how to shorten/fix my code, feel free to help me.

```js
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "KeyA") {
    letterDown = "a";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyB") {
    letterDown = "b";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyC") {
    letterDown = "c";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyD") {
    letterDown = "d";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyE") {
    letterDown = "e";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyF") {
    letterDown = "f";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyG") {
    letterDown = "g";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyH") {
    letterDown = "h";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyI") {
    letterDown = "i";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyJ") {
    letterDown = "j";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyK") {
    letterDown = "k";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyL") {
    letterDown = "l";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyM") {
    letterDown = "m";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyN") {
    letterDown = "n";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyO") {
    letterDown = "o";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyP") {
    letterDown = "p";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyQ") {
    letterDown = "q";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyR") {
    letterDown = "r";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyS") {
    letterDown = "s";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyT") {
    letterDown = "t";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyU") {
    letterDown = "u";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyV") {
    letterDown = "v";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyW") {
    letterDown = "w";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyX") {
    letterDown = "x";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyY") {
    letterDown = "y";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }else if (e.key == "KeyZ") {
    letterDown = "z";
    console.log(keyDown);
    console.log(ballLetter);
  }
}
```

I'm using JSFiddle, so maybe it's just an issue with the servers on the website. I can't think of any way to shorten the code, and if my keypress detection systems are wrong, please tell me so.

Comment: change to 1 line `letterDown = e.key.replace('Key', '').toLowerCase();`

Comment: *the function has too many statements* -> please refer to [This function has too many statements. (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038080/this-function-has-too-many-statements-41).

Comment: The message is more like a "suggestion" or "recommendation" from your tooling - probably this is a from linter.  See above link from 馬料水碼農 for more details but in short, you can ignore the warning if you want to (but it's good advice so better to do something to shorten the code).

Comment: You likely don't have to do this work at all.  If this came from a `KeyboardEvent` called `e`, and you press the `a` key on your keyboard, then `e.code` is something like `KeyA` and `e.key` will be `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```js
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  letterDown = e.key.slice(-1).toLowerCase();
  console.log(keyDown);
  console.log(ballLetter);
}
```